# How can I use a standard built-in Windows login facility in a C# WPF app to validate a user before an action?

Tags: c#, wpf, authentication, .net-4.8

How can I use a standard built-in Windows login facility in a C# WPF app to validate a local user prior to taking a requested action? I'm also limited to .NET Framework 4.8.

I want to avoid "rolling my own" to ensure standard facilities are used that are familiar to the user, and to eliminate any risk of a leak of credentials information or even the merest suggestion of potential phishing.

I have seen other user apps do this with, for example, Windows Hello PIN.

Many thanks for advice/assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Windows API [`LogonUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonusera)  function.

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, BestFitMapping = false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
internal static extern bool LogonUser(
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string pszUserName,
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string pszDomain,
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string pszPassword,
int dwLogonType,
int dwLogonProvider,
ref IntPtr phToken);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var domain = "...";
    var user = "...";
    var pwd = "...";
    var token = new IntPtr();
    var success = false;
    try
    {
        success = LogonUser(user, domain, pwd, 2/*LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE*/, 0, ref token);
    }
    finally
    {
        CloseHandle(token);
    }
}
```

Depending on your requirements you may need [`CredUIPromptForCredentials`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincred/nf-wincred-creduipromptforcredentialsa?redirectedfrom=MSDN) instead.

Comment: [`CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincred/nf-wincred-creduipromptforwindowscredentialsw) I think is better than `CredUIPromptForCredentials`. Also a `SafeHandle` is probably better than using a bare `IntPtr`

Comment: Thanks for these useful ideas. I want to highlight that the need is for **built-in** capabilities and to completely avoid having any access to plain text input. The example I gave of Windows Hello PIN does that, I expect. Any code that can achieve that? Thanks.